# MySQL Server installation failed

Tags: windows-10, mysql, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to install MySQL Server 8.0.13, During my installation, the installer needs visual studio to complete the process.

I installed Redistributable Visual C++ for Visual Studio 2015 32bit and 64 bit, but it still failed:

[image]

You find here the whole log :

```
    1: Action 22:58:55: INSTALL. 
1: 1: MySQL Server 8.0 2: {5A1AC698-82B9-4962-9FF5-EABADBA5A124} 
1: Action 22:58:55: FindRelatedProducts. Searching for related applications
1: Action 22:58:55: AppSearch. Searching for installed applications
1: Action 22:58:55: LaunchConditions. Evaluating launch conditions
1: Action 22:58:55: ValidateProductID. 
1: Action 22:58:55: CostInitialize. Computing space requirements
1: Action 22:58:55: FileCost. Computing space requirements
1: Action 22:58:55: CostFinalize. Computing space requirements
1: Action 22:58:55: MigrateFeatureStates. Migrating feature states from related applications
1: Action 22:58:55: InstallValidate. Validating install
1: Action 22:58:55: SaveTargetDir. 
1: Action 22:58:55: InstallInitialize. 
1: Action 22:58:55: RemoveExistingProducts. Removing applications
1: Action 22:58:55: ProcessComponents. Updating component registration
1: Action 22:58:57: GenerateScript. Generating script operations for action:
1: Updating component registration
1: Action 22:58:57: UnpublishFeatures. Unpublishing Product Features
1: Action 22:58:57: SchedSecureObjectsRollback. 
1: Action 22:58:57: RemoveRegistryValues. Removing system registry values
1: Action 22:58:57: RemoveShortcuts. Removing shortcuts
1: Action 22:58:57: RemoveFiles. Removing files
1: Action 22:58:57: RemoveFolders. Removing folders
1: Action 22:58:57: CreateFolders. Creating folders
1: Folder: Creating folders
1: Action 22:58:57: InstallFiles. Copying new files
1: File: Copying new files,  Directory: ,  Size: 
1: Action 22:58:58: CreateShortcuts. Creating shortcuts
1: Shortcut: Creating shortcuts
1: Action 22:58:58: WriteRegistryValues. Writing system registry values
1: Key: Writing system registry values, Name: , Value: 
1: Action 22:58:58: InstallServices. Installing new services
1: Action 22:58:58: SchedSecureObjects. 
1: Action 22:58:58: ExecSecureObjects. 
1: 
1: Action 22:58:58: RegisterUser. Registering user
1: Action 22:58:58: RegisterProduct. Registering product
1: Registering product
1: Action 22:58:58: PublishFeatures. Publishing Product Features
1: Feature: Publishing Product Features
1: Action 22:58:58: PublishProduct. Publishing product information
1: Action 22:58:58: InstallFinalize. 
1: Action 22:58:58: ProcessComponents. Updating component registration
1: Action 22:58:58: CreateFolders. Creating folders
1: Folder: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\
1: Folder: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\
1: Folder: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\mysql\
1: Folder: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\performance_schema\
1: Folder: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data\test\
1: Action 22:58:58: InstallFiles. Copying new files
1: File: harness-library.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 588288
1: File: ibd2sdi.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5099008
1: File: innochecksum.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5060608
1: File: libeay32.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 2102272
1: File: libmecab.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 1839616
1: File: lz4_decompress.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 4948992
1: File: my_print_defaults.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 4957184
1: File: myisam_ftdump.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5219328
1: File: myisamchk.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5329408
1: File: myisamlog.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5180416
1: File: myisampack.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5241344
1: File: mysql.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5292544
1: File: mysql_config.pl,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 7392
1: File: mysql_config_editor.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 4974080
1: File: mysql_secure_installation.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5180416
1: File: mysql_ssl_rsa_setup.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5006336
1: File: mysql_tzinfo_to_sql.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 4904448
1: File: mysql_upgrade.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 11032576
1: File: mysqladmin.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5188096
1: File: mysqlbinlog.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5491712
1: File: mysqlcheck.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5200384
1: File: mysqld.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 46325760
1: File: mysqld_multi.pl,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 28045
1: File: mysqldump.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5261312
1: File: mysqldumpslow.pl,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 8071
1: File: mysqlimport.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5180928
1: File: mysqlpump.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5666304
1: File: mysqlrouter.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5713408
1: File: mysqlrouter_plugin_info.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 43520
1: File: mysqlshow.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5179904
1: File: mysqlslap.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5197312
1: File: perror.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 5614592
1: File: resolveip.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 4955136
1: File: ssleay32.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 356864
1: File: zlib_decompress.exe,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\,  Size: 4923392
1: File: sample_mysqlrouter.conf,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\docs\,  Size: 2170
1: File: mysqlrouter.conf.sample,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\etc\,  Size: 1267
1: File: binary_log_types.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\,  Size: 2886
1: File: errmsg.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\,  Size: 5294
1: File: my_command.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\,  Size: 4385
1: File: my_list.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\,  Size: 2603
1: File: mysql.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\,  Size: 31305
1: File: client_plugin.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\mysql\,  Size: 7295
1: File: mysql_com.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\,  Size: 34068
1: File: plugin_auth_common.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\mysql\,  Size: 5546
1: File: mysql_time.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\,  Size: 2996
1: File: udf_registration_types.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\mysql\,  Size: 3848
1: File: mysql_version.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\,  Size: 1054
1: File: mysqld_error.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\,  Size: 199232
1: File: mysqlx_ername.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\,  Size: 4745
1: File: mysqlx_error.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\,  Size: 2954
1: File: mysqlx_version.h,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\,  Size: 1861
1: File: applink.c,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\include\openssl\,  Size: 3176
1: File: keepalive.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\,  Size: 22528
1: File: libmysql.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\,  Size: 5165056
1: File: libmysql.lib,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\,  Size: 27298
1: File: char.bin,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_euc-jp\,  Size: 262496
1: File: dicrc,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_euc-jp\,  Size: 693
1: File: left-id.def,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_euc-jp\,  Size: 55910
1: File: matrix.bin,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_euc-jp\,  Size: 3463716
1: File: pos-id.def,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_euc-jp\,  Size: 1477
1: File: rewrite.def,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_euc-jp\,  Size: 6241
1: File: right-id.def,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_euc-jp\,  Size: 55910
1: File: sys.dic,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_euc-jp\,  Size: 37779919
1: File: unk.dic,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_euc-jp\,  Size: 5409
1: File: char.bin,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_sjis\,  Size: 262496
1: File: dicrc,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_sjis\,  Size: 693
1: File: left-id.def,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_sjis\,  Size: 55910
1: File: matrix.bin,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_sjis\,  Size: 3463716
1: File: pos-id.def,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_sjis\,  Size: 1477
1: File: rewrite.def,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_sjis\,  Size: 6241
1: File: right-id.def,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_sjis\,  Size: 55910
1: File: sys.dic,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_sjis\,  Size: 37635899
1: File: unk.dic,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_sjis\,  Size: 5409
1: File: char.bin,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_utf-8\,  Size: 262496
1: File: dicrc,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_utf-8\,  Size: 693
1: File: left-id.def,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_utf-8\,  Size: 55910
1: File: matrix.bin,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_utf-8\,  Size: 3463716
1: File: pos-id.def,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_utf-8\,  Size: 1477
1: File: rewrite.def,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_utf-8\,  Size: 6241
1: File: right-id.def,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_utf-8\,  Size: 55910
1: File: sys.dic,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_utf-8\,  Size: 49199027
1: File: unk.dic,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\dic\ipadic_utf-8\,  Size: 5690
1: File: mecabrc,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\mecab\etc\,  Size: 1403
1: File: metadata_cache.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\,  Size: 5513728
1: File: mysql_protocol.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\,  Size: 91648
1: File: mysqlclient.lib,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\,  Size: 61593696
1: File: mysqlrouter_lib.lib,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\,  Size: 24771182
1: File: adt_null.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 24064
1: File: component_log_filter_dragnet.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 31744
1: File: component_log_sink_json.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 16384
1: File: component_log_sink_syseventlog.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 17408
1: File: component_validate_password.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 65536
1: File: connection_control.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 47104
1: File: group_replication.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 1263104
1: File: ha_example.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 28672
1: File: ha_mock.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 41472
1: File: keyring_file.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 108544
1: File: keyring_udf.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 25088
1: File: libpluginmecab.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 30720
1: File: locking_service.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 13312
1: File: mypluglib.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 13312
1: File: mysql_no_login.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 12288
1: File: rewrite_example.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 13312
1: File: rewriter.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 65536
1: File: semisync_master.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 76288
1: File: semisync_slave.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 29696
1: File: validate_password.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 53760
1: File: version_token.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\plugin\,  Size: 62976
1: File: routing.dll,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\,  Size: 438784
1: File: LICENSE,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\,  Size: 335809
1: File: LICENSE.router,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\,  Size: 101807
1: File: README,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\,  Size: 687
1: File: README.router,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\,  Size: 700
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\bulgarian\,  Size: 267964
1: File: armscii8.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 5939
1: File: ascii.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 5925
1: File: cp1250.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 8654
1: File: cp1251.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 8783
1: File: cp1256.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 5982
1: File: cp1257.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 9315
1: File: cp850.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 5919
1: File: cp852.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 5941
1: File: cp866.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 6026
1: File: dec8.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 6942
1: File: geostd8.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 5929
1: File: greek.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 6141
1: File: hebrew.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 5930
1: File: hp8.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 5915
1: File: Index.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 19495
1: File: keybcs2.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 5942
1: File: koi8r.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 5923
1: File: koi8u.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 6945
1: File: latin1.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 10229
1: File: latin2.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 7651
1: File: latin5.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 5928
1: File: latin7.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 7851
1: File: macce.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 8460
1: File: macroman.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 8471
1: File: README,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 1749
1: File: swe7.xml,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\charsets\,  Size: 6943
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\czech\,  Size: 268470
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\danish\,  Size: 268470
1: File: dictionary.txt,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\,  Size: 25575
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\dutch\,  Size: 269490
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\english\,  Size: 267711
1: File: errmsg-utf8.txt,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\,  Size: 841806
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\estonian\,  Size: 267975
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\french\,  Size: 269118
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\german\,  Size: 275342
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\greek\,  Size: 274502
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\hungarian\,  Size: 268352
1: File: innodb_memcached_config.sql,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\,  Size: 3999
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\italian\,  Size: 269481
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\japanese\,  Size: 275157
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\korean\,  Size: 270751
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\norwegian\,  Size: 267781
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\norwegian-ny\,  Size: 267834
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\polish\,  Size: 268640
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\portuguese\,  Size: 270671
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\romanian\,  Size: 269423
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\russian\,  Size: 282986
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\serbian\,  Size: 270092
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\slovak\,  Size: 268237
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\spanish\,  Size: 269365
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\swedish\,  Size: 268564
1: File: errmsg.sys,  Directory: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\share\ukrainian\,  Size: 277560
1: Action 22:59:05: CreateShortcuts. Creating shortcuts
1: Shortcut: icon.ico
1: Shortcut: Icon.MysqlCmdShell
1: Shortcut: rpxm3ds_|MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client
1: Shortcut: 7ejegqmo|MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client - Unicode
1: Action 22:59:05: WriteRegistryValues. Writing system registry values
1: Key: \SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 8.0, Name: Location, Value: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\
1: Key: \SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 8.0, Name: Version, Value: 8.0.13
1: Key: \SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 8.0, Name: DataLocation, Value: C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\
1: Key: \SOFTWARE\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 8.0, Name: , Value: 
1: Key: \Console\MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client - Unicode, Name: FaceName, Value: Lucida Console
1: Key: \Console\MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client - Unicode, Name: FontWeight, Value: #400
1: Key: \Console\MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client - Unicode, Name: , Value: 
1: Key: \Software\MySQL AB\MySQL Server 8.0, Name: installed, Value: #1
1: Action 22:59:05: ExecSecureObjects. 
1: Action 22:59:05: Rollback. Rolling back action:
1: ExecSecureObjects
1: Writing system registry values
1: Creating shortcuts
1: Copying new files
1: Creating folders
1: Updating component registration
1: 1: MySQL Server 8.0 2: {5A1AC698-82B9-4962-9FF5-EABADBA5A124} 3: 3 
1: The action 'Install' for product 'MySQL Server 8.0.13' failed.
```

Comment: It would help if you [edit] your question and show the output of clicking "Show Details" ...

Comment: @DavidPostill I think, it's good now

Comment: No it's not....

Comment: I edited the post again, I'm not sure if it shown, generally the status of instalation of mySQL server is failed

Comment: Yes. But you don't show the output of clicking "Show Details". Please click that button and provide a new screen shot.

Comment: Without the log, which indicates the reason for the failure, this question cannot be answered.  More interested in the reason you installed VC++ 2015 instead of a different version.

Comment: @Ramhound I added the log

Comment: @DavidPostill I think, it's better now

Comment: @Noureddine - I think the answer you are looking for may lie within a thread on this post.... https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=92392. Keeping reading thru it and checking off the items you've done, if not, then try them but read the entire post before doing anything. And of course be sure you have backups.